# function that computes significant jump test from high frequency data for repeated number of days

Tags: r

I am trying run jump significant tests for high frequency data using the Ait-Sahala Methodology (AJjumptest) in R i have loaded d data as an xts object and do proper data cleaning but the jump test can only be done for intraday data and i have been doing this one after the other using this code:
    library(highfrequncy)
    library(xts)
    setwd('C:/Users/Lufemos/Desktop/CROSS PAIRS/CHFJPY')

```
CHFJPY_2010 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2010.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

CHFJPY_2011 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2011.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
CHFJPY_2012 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2012.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
CHFJPY_2013 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2013.csv",  ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
CHFJPY_2014 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2014.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
CHFJPY_2015 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2015.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
CHFJPY_2016 <- read_delim("CHFJPY_2016.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

    rbind(CHFJPY_2010,CHFJPY_2011,CHFJPY_2012,CHFJPY_2013,CHFJPY_2014,CHFJPY_2015,CHFJPY_2016)

names(CHFJPY)=c('dt', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'x')
CHFJPY$X = NULL

CHFJPY$mid_price = (CHFJPY$high+CHFJPY$low)/2
```

But this is taking a lot of time as i have data containing over 2500 days. I am looking for a function that will compute the significant jump test using the indicated methodology and return the number of days with significant jumps

Comment: Hi there. I'd recommend editing your question so as to clarify what you're asking. You've made a statement of what you're doing and that it takes a long time, however you haven't actually asked a specific question? If it's that the algorithm is taking too long, perhaps it's just how long that particular algorithm takes?

Comment: The method i am using is time consuming as i have to compute the significant test for each of the exchange dates one after the other, What i want to know is if there is a customized R function that can compute the significant test for all of the days in the data set and return the number of days where we have significant tests

Comment: The method i am using is time consuming as i have to compute the significant test for each of the exchange dates one after the other, What i want to know is if there is a customized R function that can compute the significant test for all of the days in the data set and return the number of days where we have significant tests, for example, a significant test for a day gives this result : $ztest
[1] -2.746792

$critical.value
[1] -1.959964  1.959964

$pvalue
[1] 0.006018128